# Prepend data from one file to another

Tags: linux, file, shell, prepend

How do I prepend the data from file1.txt to file2.txt?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The following command will take the two files and merge them into one

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt; mv file3.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: good call, didnt think about the fact that it is being written to itself.  An intermediary file then.  and then mv.  adjusting answer to suit

Comment: So, so simple. Thanks a lot, going the `sed` route makes absolutely no sense here.

Comment: Note to people who see this answer: DO NOT try to do that in one command like `cat file1.txt file2.txt > file2.txt`.  It will run in an infinite loop.  I got about 10 seconds in before I hit ctrl+C.  8817181 lines from a 13 line file and a 7 line file.  The original comment that answerer replied to was deleted, so it's not clear that that was a problem.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this in a pipeline using `sponge` from `moreutils`:

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt | sponge file2.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

Another way using GNU sed:

```
sed -i -e '1rfile1.txt' -e '1{h;d}' -e '2{x;G}' file2.txt
```

That is:

- On line 1, append the content of the file `file1.txt`
- On line 1, copy pattern space to hold space, and delete pattern space
- On line 2, exchange the content of the hold and pattern spaces, and append the hold space to pattern space

The reason it's a bit tricky is that the `r` command appends content,
and line 0 is not addressable, so we have to do it on line 1,
moving the content of the original line out of the way and then bringing it back after the content of the file is appended.

Comment: macos:  you can install gsed (macports, probably homebrew too).  that said, I ended up with just the contents of file1, file2's content was lost.

Comment: nice answer, this one does not require anything to be installed on Ubuntu, also does not make any garbage files.

Comment: This doesn't work if `file2.txt` contains a single line

Answer (score 2):

If it's available on your system, then [sponge](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/sponge.1.html) from moreutils is designed for this. Here is an example:

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt | sponge file2.txt
```

If you don't have `sponge`, then the following script does the same job using a temporary file. It makes sure that the temporary file is not accessible by other users, and cleans it up at the end.

If your system, or the script crashes, you may need to clean up the temporary file manually. Tested on Bash 4.4.23, and Debian 10 (Buster) Gnu/Linux.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# usage [ from, to ]
#       [ from, to ]
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# Purpose:
# Prepend the contents of file [from], to file [to], leaving the result in file [to].
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

# check 
[[ $# -ne 2 ]] && echo "[exit]: two filenames are required" >&2 && exit 1

# init
from="$1"
to="$2"
tmp_fn=$( mktemp -t TEMP_FILE_prepend.XXXXXXXX )
chmod 600 "$tmp_fn"

# prepend
cat "$from" "$to" > "$tmp_fn"
mv "$tmp_fn" "$to"

# cleanup
rm -f "$tmp_fn"

# [End]
```

Answer (score -1):

The way of writing file is like 1). append at the end of the file or 2). rewrite that file.

If you want to put the content in file1.txt ahead of file2.txt, I'm afraid you need to rewrite  the combined fine.